# Expression of timezone offset - clarification

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

Something I'm currently working on requires localised times for users around the world. All datetimes are stored as UTC, so converting them is easy enough and we have a known, safe, point of reference, etc, etc.

However, something about how the offset is expressed is making me scratch my head a moment.

```
>>> timezone.now()  # get the UTC-stamped server time as an example
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 21, 16, 37, 54, 62598, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>> eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')  # localise this to US/Eastern
>>> utc_dt.astimezone(eastern)
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 21, 12, 37, 54, 62598,   
    tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

(That's my line break in the datetime output, just to make it easier to spot the bit I'm on about.)

That expression of the offset seems, well, a bit over the top. Rather than simply saying it's an offset of -4h from UTC, it looks like it's saying it's minus one day plus 20:00 hours. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure why the text is formed that way, but it is just debug output, right?  Does it really matter then how it is formatted?  You will probably use `strftime` or similar when using in your application.

Comment: Also, you should know that the `US/*` time zones are aliases and there for backwards compatibility reasons.  You should probably use `America/New_York` instead.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for a list.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, America/New_York, Chicago etc are what we'll really use, but I just used US/Eastern as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the `repr` of the `pytz` timezone class, which includes implementation details that shouldn't matter when you use it in real life. If you `print` that same object you'll see something different:

```
>>> print utc_dt.astimezone(eastern)
2013-05-21 15:00:27.648000-04:00
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes perfect sense. Any idea, though, why it's implemented that way? Am curious.

Comment: @stevejalim, sorry I don't have any insight into the inner workings of pytz.